# Make css file affect in each of difference section in Angular 9

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm creating a project with angular.

My project devide with two primary section: **admin**, **home**. I have two template for each of that section.

Now I want to create each section, which has its own css file.

Example in **admin** section will have files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

And in **home** section will have files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./home/assets/css/main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./home/assets/css/custom.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./home/assets/css/green.css">
```

If i import all of **css** files into **index.html**, my GUI will jump messy.
Is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 0):

import the stylesheets in the components css/scss file.

For example, for admin component, then import the bootstrap  css as follows

```
@import url('/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

in admin.component.css(scss)

Also, try to use sass since it is much easier and flexible

Comment: So example, all components in admin section are reused from layout component by **<app-layout>**, if i import css in layout.component, could i need to import them again when i write html code in another file of admin section?